# How to map events of POSIX's select and Windows WSAEventSelect

Tags: winapi, select, networking, posix, winsock

POSIX's select allows to determine 3 events:

- read
- write
- error

Window's WSAEventSelect has 10:

- FD_READ
- FD_WRITE
- FD_OOB
- FD_ACCEPT
- FD_CONNECT
- FD_CLOSE
- FD_QOS
- FD_GROUP_QOS
- FD_ROUTING_INTERFACE_CHANGE
- FD_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE

How can I map those Windows events to POSIX events?

**EDIT**

Unfortunately I cannot use Windows's implementation of `select` because of the [multiple providers restriction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739177(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You could use `select(..)` as well if you don't need to wait for the network events using a WSAEVENT ... it is defined in winsock2.h

Comment: @LukasThomsen I cannot use `select` because it does not allow to mix sockets from different providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping between `select()` and `WSAEventSelect()` is not that hard to figure out if you read the documentation.

[select function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx)

[WSAEventSelect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576.aspx)

`select()` reports a socket is readable when:

1. the socket is listening and has a pending inbound connection waiting to be accepted (`FD_ACCEPT`)
2. the socket has pending data waiting to be read (`FD_READ`). This includes Out-Of-Band data if the `SO_OOBINLINE` option is enabled on the socket.
3. the socket has been closed gracefully by the peer (`FD_CLOSE`, which also handles some ungraceful closures as well).

`select()` reports a socket is writable when:

1. a non-blocking `connect()` has successfully connected to a listening port (`FD_CONNECT` with a zero error code)
2. the socket has buffer space to accept outbound data (`FD_WRITE`) after being accepted, or after a previous non-blocking send will no longer block.

`select()` reports an exception on a socket when:

1. a non-blocking `connect()` has failed (`FD_CONNECT` with a non-zero error code).  You can use `getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR)` to get the error code.
2. the socket has pending Out-Of-Band data waiting to be read if the `SO_OOBINLINE` option is disabled on the socket (`FD_OOB`).
3. various socket errors have occurred.

There are no `select()` equivalents for the rest of the WSA events, as they are strictly WinSock-specific extensions not related to POSIX/BSD socket APIs.

So, you would use `WSAEventSelect()` to setup the desired `FD_...` events, then wait on the events using [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219.aspx).  When an event is signaled, use [`WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741572.aspx) to get the associated error codes and clear the event state for the next wait.

Comment: How would I figure out that connect failed with an error code?

Comment: What is the source of this mapping?

Comment: @Kentzo: MSDN documentation.

Comment: Each event may fail with error, but you only mentioned FD_CONNECT. Why didn't you mention the rest?

Comment: @Kentzo: `select()` does not differentiate errors for specific events, whereas `WSAEventSelect()` does.  At least with `connect()`, `select()` reports writable if the connection attempt succeeds, and an exception state otherwise, so you can differentiate (you have to use `getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR)` to get the actual error code). I did say "*When an event is signaled, use WSAEnumNetworkEvents() to get the associated error codes*". You asked how to map `WSAEventSelect()` events to `select()`, not the other way around.

Comment: In my case, I only use WSA to wait for a signal of state change, then I enumerate list of sockets and sets from different providers and use select without delay. This is a hack to pass limitation of WSAWaitForMultipleEvents. Ultimately I need to know which events signaled by WSA will lead for select to signal as well.